# Crystal report open in a new Window/browser tab using button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am using Vb.net(webapp) code to generate monthly payment history. So I have a button on payment duration selection page and want generate a Crystal report in new tab/ window after clicking the generate report button?

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose you crystal report page name is (CRPage).
So you can use the following to open that page using:

```
Response.Write("<script>")
Response.Write("window.open('CRPage.aspx')")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but  my app is trying to call CrystalreportViewer1 which is placed inside the payment page. If I try to place it to another page it is not getting the parent class in .aspx page.